# Stuck at login screen on fresh install

Tags: 18.04, login, password, login-screen

So I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an unformatted SSD using a USB boot media I flashed from macOS.

I used the minimal install, and selected install 3rd party drivers from the options, as well as the option to download updates during install.

The install process finished, and when I try to login using the password I provided during the install, the screen just goes black for a few seconds, and then the login screen comes back up.

I know I am using the correct password, because if I use a different password, it gives me an error and asks for the password again.

I tried re-installing from the flash drive again and I get the same result.

Please help!  How do I get to my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging in at the usual login screen with Xorg instead of Wayland. Click the gear icon to the left of the  <kbd>Sign In</kbd>  button and select *Ubuntu on Xorg* from the dropdown menu. This selection will be persistent across reboots unless you switch back to Wayland.

[image: select Ubuntu on Xorg]

If that doesn't work try switching the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. LightDM is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3. Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install lightdm   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm 
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running `sudo reboot`

Comment: It works!  Actually mine showed Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland as options, and I had to switch it to wayland for it to work.  What's the difference between these options?

Comment: The choice of options in the Sign In dropdown menu depends on whether or not you have installed a proprietary graphics driver because proprietary graphics drivers are not compatible with Wayland (so you can't login), but the open source graphics drivers are compatible with Wayland.

Comment: ok thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: this method will close all graphical programs and unsaved data will be lost. Solution:

1. Press ctrl+alt+f3
2. Login
3. Restart X11 by running: "sudo systemctl restart display-manager"
4. Return to the GUI login screen by pressing ctrl+alt+f1
5. Login and be sad that you lost the data in your GUI programs :[

This is better than restarting the computer in my case because I have an external HDD mounted which takes time and multiple tries in order to mount it in a stable way. I had the problem of being stuck in the login screen when trying to unlock a locked desktop.